# can these templates be made unambiguous

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers

I'm trying to create a set of overloaded templates for arrays/pointers where one template will be used when the compiler knows the size of the array and the other template will be used when it doesn't:

```
template <typename T, size_t SZ>
void moo(T (&arr)[SZ])
{ ... }

template <typename T>
void moo(T *ptr)
{ ... }
```

The problem is that when the compiler knows the size of the array, the overloads are ambiguous and the compile fails.

Is there some way to resolve the ambiguity (perhaps via SFINAE) or is this just not possible.

Comment: Shouldn't the second overload have a `size_t` parameter or something so the function will know the size of the array pointed by `ptr`?

Comment: The pointer version doesn't necessarily have to be for dynamic arrays. @ins

Comment: Good question, I stumbled upon the exact same issue. For the record, the ambiguity arises because array-to-pointer conversion is considered an exact match during overload resolution (§13.3.3.1.1). I don't find this a very intuitive behavior, and I would be interested in knowing why such a decision was made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible as it can be determined wether a template parameter is an array or not:

```
template<class T> struct is_array {
    enum { value = false }; 
};
template<class T, size_t N> struct is_array<T[N]> {
   enum { value = true }; 
};
template<class T> void f(T const&) { 
    std::cout << is_array<T>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Combining that with `enable_if`, the above can be made unambiguous. For example using Boost.TypeTraits:

```
template <typename T, size_t SZ>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_array<T>, void>::type
f(T (&arr)[SZ]) {}
```

With references however there is no need for SFINAE at all:

```
template<class T, size_t SZ> void f(T (&arr)[SZ]) {}
template<class T>            void f(T* const& t)  {}
```

Johannes brings up another option that fits the situation at hand better - using SFINAE for the problematic pointer overload instead:

```
template <typename T, size_t SZ> void f(T (&arr)[SZ]) {}
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_pointer<T>, void>::type
f(T ptr) {}
```

Comment: If you change the second function to `T* const& t` you can even accept rvalue pointer expressions. To show how he would use your template in *his* scenario: `template<typename T, size_t SZ> void f(T (&arr)[SZ]) { } template<typename T> typename disable_if< is_array<T> >::type void f(T const& t) { }`. Ultimately, i would use a `is_pointer` to do this with `enable_if`, beause it's the array binding to the `T*` that makes the problem, not the pointer binding to `T[N]` (which wouldn't work).

Comment: @Johannes: I guess i tend to overlook rvalues until they hit me. As usual, thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 2):

And probably the easiest solution:

```
template <typename T, size_t SZ>
void moo(T (&arr)[SZ])
{ ... }

template <typename T>
inline void moo(T ptr) { __moo(ptr); }

template <typename T>
void __moo(T* ptr)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function explicitly:

```
int a[1] = {0}
moo<int,1>(a);
```

Or you can overload on const:

```
template<class T>
void moo(T const* p) { }

// ...
moo(a); // not const, array

int* p = 0;
moo(p); // pointer
```